# Kotlin: heapsort неправильно работает

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка, kotlin

На маленьких массивах все ОК, на средних и больших неверно работает. Что я делаю не так?

UPDATE:
Переписал старый код, но все равное не работает правильно.

```
 fun sort(arr: Array< Int>) {

    var k: Int = Math.floor((arr.size() - 1) / 2.0).toInt()
    var heapSize: Int = arr.size() - 1

    while ( heapSize != 1) {

        builtHeap(arr, heapSize, k)
        swap(arr, 0, heapSize)
        heapSize--
        k = Math.floor((heapSize-1 ) / 2.0).toInt()
    }
 }

 fun builtHeap(arr:Array< Int>, hs:Int,  k: Int): Array< Int> {
    var i=0

    while (i != k) {
       heapify(arr, i, hs)
       arr.printArray()
       i++
    }
    return arr
 }

 fun heapify( arr:Array< Int>, ind: Int, heapSize: Int) {
    var left: Int = ind*2+1
    var right: Int = ind*2+2

    if((left < heapSize)&&(arr[left] > arr[ind]))
       swap(arr, left, ind)

    if((right < heapSize)&&(arr[right] > arr[ind]))
       swap(arr, right, ind)
  }

  fun swap(arr: Array< Int>, ind1: Int, ind2: Int): Array< Int> {

    var tmp: Int = arr[ind1]
    arr[ind1] = arr[ind2]
    arr[ind2] = tmp
    return arr
  }

  fun Array<out Any>.printArray() {
     this.forEach {
        print("$it ")
     }
     println()
  }

  fun main(args: Array<String>) {

     val array = arrayOf(4,1,3,2,43,12,78 )
     array.printArray()

     sort(array)
     array.printArray()
  }
```

Comment: Непонятно, как работает алгоритм. например, в функции heapify оба условия if всегда равны false, так как left и right всегда больше heapSize..

Comment: В функции sort heapSize уменьшается в цикле while при каждой итерации

Comment: Я смотрю нв вызов этой функции из buildHeap и совершенно не понимю, что вызов heapify из этой функции делает?

Comment: Маленькие и большие массивы - это какие?

Comment: Извиняюсь за отсутствие точности. Имел в виду, что на массивах длиной n, где  n < 7 все в порядке, в остальны случаях - нет.